# How to use yaml env file in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the .env file as yaml format, in other words I have `development.yaml` file which consists of following let's say:

```
server:
  port: 3000
  apiPrefix: api/v1
  swagger:
    title: Test
    description: test description
    version: 1.0
    api: /docs
database:
  name: test
  autoLoadModels: true
  synchronize: false
  dialect: postgres
```

and inside `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  dev:
    env_file:
      - config/development.yaml
    container_name: test_development_api_docker_container
    image: test_development_api_docker_container:1.0.0
    build:
      context: .
      target: testDevelopmentEnv
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: npm run start:debug
    ports:
      - ${port}:${port}
    networks:
      - test_network
    volumes:
      - .:/Users/falyoun/dev/ite/test
      - /Users/falyoun/dev/ite/test/node_modules
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  test_network:
```

In the above file I tried:

- ${port}
- ${server.port}

and all causes issues like

> ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "ports" option in service "dev": "${server.port}:${server.port}"

or

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
> services.dev.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object

Comment: The [Compose `.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) is a flat `KEY=value` format, not YAML.  Where did this configuration file come from?  It seems like it might better match, say, the Kubernetes [Helm](https://helm.sh) tool, not Compose.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes I do know what form of .env file is, but I've the configuration stored in `.yaml` file and I do need it to load it to docker-compose

Answer (score 1):

Before you try anything, you should switch from:

```
docker-compose
```

to:

```
docker compose
```

The docker-compose tool has been deprecated, and is at this point a fairly stale version (1.25.X) as installed by apt install.  Instead, you should remove docker-compose from your computer and install docker-compose-plugin (latest version as of today is 2.6.X).